# How to get values out of an for each loop

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
public function get_contents() {

    $items = array();

    foreach($this->items as $tmpItem) {
        $item = null;
        $item['id']       = $tmpItem;
        $item['name']     = $this->names[$tmpItem];
        $item['price']    = $this->prices[$tmpItem];
        $item['qty']      = $this->qtys[$tmpItem];
        $item['X']  = $this->X$tmpItem];
        $items[]          = $item;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

I would like to get the values of X.
So if there are 3 loops with for example no,no,yes for the value of X how would I be able to use these values.

I have tried the following

```
public function update_X($X){
    foreach($this->items as $item) {
        if(strstr($this->Xs[$item], 'no') ==!false){
            $this->Xs = 'no';
            $item['X']      = $this->Xs;
        }
        else    
            $this->Xs = 'yes';
        $item['X']      = $this->Xs;
    }
}
```

It will only use the last value for X that is added. So in this case it would be 'yes'. What I want if there is any value for the X that is no the value for $item['X'] is 'no.

Any help welcome

Comment: Please try to express your problem in a more understanding manner. Show an example of input and expected output.

Comment: Your first example shows how you use an array outside the for loop to store multiple results. Why can't you do that in the second example. Or, you can try to use the yield function to return multiple items from the function inside the loop.

Comment: @kainaw if I can retrieve all the values for just the X and print is something like $X = no. no, yes that would be great. I just don't know how to get to it. At the minute it just shows the last value which is '$X = 'yes'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always resetting the Xs, not concatenating. That's why you always get only the last value.

Try this:

```
$Xs="";
foreach($this->items as $item) {
    $Xs.=$this->X[$item];
}
// $Xs is now "nonoyes"
```

Comment: Thanks so much that done it. Sorry didn't have a chance to reply yet.